# Editando o nome do pacote no Intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk, google-play

Criei um Aplicativo no Intel XDK e na hora de publicar na google play, dá o seguinte erro:

> Use um nome de pacote diferente. "xdk.intel.blank.ad.template" já existe no Google Play

Como faço para alterar o nome do pacote, e onde insiro o nome ao criar para que não aconteça de novo? Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

No lado esquerdo superior tem a aba ***Projects***, clica lá, depois vá para ***build settings***, Aba ***Android*** e altere o ***App ID*** que é esse nome do pacote.

Comment: Isso pelo painel do Google play Console ? Ou no Android Studio ?